# Is $x^2\cos(1/x)$ uniformly continuous on $(1,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have got a question.

Is $f(x)=x^2\cos(1/x)$ uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,1)$
?

And how to prove/disprove it.

Using the hint from ajotatxe, it is easy to see the both the two limits tend to zero. So can I just say that to conclude the function is uniformly continuous?

I was thinking proving $cos(1/x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. Then by composition of continuous functions the function is continuous on a bounded interval so it is uniformly continuous. But I was struggling with the proof of continuity of $cos(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$.

I can prove that $|cos(1/x)-cos(1/y)|\le|1/x-1/y|$. But how to use it to prove $cos(1/x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I assume you mean on $(0,1)$? In any case can you bound $|x^2\cos(1/x)|$?

Comment: You can continuously extend it to $[0,1]$ by defining $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=\cos(1)$. Then use the Heine-Cantor theorem.

Comment: The derivative $f'(x) = \sin x^{-1} + 2x \cos x^{-1}$is bounded in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

We may extend the domain of $f$ to $[0,1]$ by putting $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=\cos 1.$ Then $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and therefore uniformly continuous on $[0,1],$ because $[0,1]$ is a closed bounded interval. So $f$ is uniformly continuous on any subset of $[0,1].$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let 
$$a_n=\frac2{(2n+1)\pi}$$
$$b_n=\frac1{n\pi}$$

Try to compute $\lim |a_n-b_n|$ and $\lim|f(a_n)-f(b_n)|$.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Characterization_via_sequences), too.

Comment: It seems the function is uniformly continuous. But can I use these two sequences to directly prove that? I was thinking proving $cos(1/x)$ is continuous on (1,0). Then the function is continuous on a bounded interval so it is uniformly continuous.